# jQuery syntax when calling masonry

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have this part of code to add elements to a masonry table.

```
            function( newElements ) {
            var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).css('display', 'none');
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){

                jQuery('.gallery').bxSlider({
                    auto: false,
                    pager: false,
                    adaptiveHeight: false
                }); 
                $newElems.css('display', 'block');
                container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                });
            }
```

After images are loaded we apply the bxSlider and after that the masonry bricks are added.
My question is who can I apply the slider only to the new elements that have th class "galery" and not in every element with this name in the DOM.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I see that your already using **class** selector,which would apply bxslider to elements that has ".gallery" class. so what exactly is your problem with current  implementaion ?

Comment: The problem is that there are many more elemets in the same page with the same class that bxslider is allready applied before. I want it to be applied only to the new elements. Maybe somenting like this.
$newElems.jQuery('.gallery').bxSlider({
but i cant find the correct syntax.

Comment: well there is simple logic for this. if you observe in firebug console all the elements which have been bxslider would have a specific set of classes applied to it. so you can verify the element to see if it has that class or not and then apply to that specifically.`$('img .gallery').each(function() { if(!($(this).hasClass('bxclassname')) ) {//Add the bxslider to it   } });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).css('display', 'none');
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        jQuery('.gallery', $newElems).bxSlider({//<<<<< specify context for the jQuery selector
            auto: false,
            pager: false,
            adaptiveHeight: false
        }); 
        $newElems.css('display', 'block');
        container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });
}
```

Alternatively, find the `.gallery` elements *within* `$newElems` :

```
$newElems.find('.gallery').bxSlider({...});
```

or find the `.gallery` elements *amongst* `$newElems` :

```
$newElems.filter('.gallery').bxSlider({{...});
```